# Java: looking for a library to read LDAP data

Tags: java, ldap

I need to write an application that will export some data from a LDAP server and store it in a MySQL DB. Is there a suitable Java library for that?

All I've found so far is jLDAP being mentioned in one of SO questions, but the site I found offers two binaries of jldap: one for Windows and one for Unix, not a single jar file as I expected.

Will be grateful for any hints towards exporting LDAP data with Java.

Comment: Did you consider JNDI?

Comment: @EJP, yes, but I wanted to have something with a simpler API than JNDI.

Comment: Then you should have said so in your question. I've used e.g. the Netscape API and I certainly don't consider it any simpler than JNDI. Critics of JNDI consider it if anything *too* simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UnboundID LDAP SDK for Java is free, open source, feature-rich, actively developed, and does not have any external dependencies.

Comment: After some consideration decided to stick to this one as it comes in a single Jar with no dependencies, has lots of good examples and is a bit smaller than Apache Directory Client API.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Apache Directory Client API](http://directory.apache.org/api/five-minutes-tutorial.html).

Comment: This API seems to be a pretty nice one, though it requires a lot of other libraries and their user guide is out of synch with real classes. Still it's possible to use it. Hope it grows into someting big.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Novell LDAP java libraries](http://www.novell.com/developer/ndk/ldap_classes_for_java.html)

Comment: Unfortunately the Novell Libraries have not had any attention form Novell in YEARS.